# wxWidgets не линкуется статически из-за множества undefined reference

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, wxwidgets

Скомпилировал wxWidgets строкой mingw32-make -j8 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 в надежде линковать библиотеки статически. В используемой Eclipse IDE сделал всё, как нужно: задефайнил `__WXMSW__`; прописал include и путь к библиотекам lib*.a; указал на библиотеки wxmsw32ud_core, wxbase32ud; в флагах линкера написал -static. Компиляция тестового кода падает из-за каких-то undefined reference:

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build
> windres.exe --use-temp-file -I "D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\include" "D:/C++/Projects/Test\resources\res.rc" "D:/C++/Projects/Test\resources\res.o"
> g++ "-LD:\C++\wxWidgets_static\lib\gcc_lib" -static -o Test.exe "src\Test.o" -lwxmsw32ud_core -lwxbase32ud
> (много ошибок, подобных тем, что ниже)
> d:/c++/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase32ud.a(baselib_filename.o):filename.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.IID_IPersistFile[.refptr.IID_IPersistFile]+0x0): undefined reference to `IID_IPersistFile' d:/c++/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase32ud.a(baselib_filename.o):filename.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.IID_IShellLinkW[.refptr.IID_IShellLinkW]+0x0): undefined reference to` IID_IShellLinkW'
> d:/c++/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase32ud.a(baselib_dlmsw.o): in function `GetFileVersion': D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\build\msw/../../src/msw/dlmsw.cpp:64: undefined reference to` GetFileVersionInfoSizeW'
> d:/c++/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\build\msw/../../src/msw/dlmsw.cpp:68: undefined reference to `GetFileVersionInfoW' d:/c++/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\build\msw/../../src/msw/dlmsw.cpp:72: undefined reference to` VerQueryValueW'
> d:/c++/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\lib\gcc_lib\libwxbase32ud.a(baselib_utils.o): in function `wxCmpNatural(wxString const&, wxString const&)': D:\C++\wxWidgets_static\build\msw/../../src/msw/utils.cpp:1692: undefined reference to` __imp_StrCmpLogicalW'

Интернет ничем не помог.

Comment: Это все функции WinAPI, их нельзя прилинковать статически.

Comment: @user7860670 , а как тогда wxWidgets статически линковать вообще? Ведь как-то же получается у кого-то

Comment: wxWidgets линкуйте статически, а WinAPI, которые он использует, - динамически

Comment: @user7860670 , не знаю, как это сделать. Как ни крути, при статической линковке будут одни и те же ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Самому угадывать флаги для компиляции библиотеки - это уж совсем каменный век.

Большинство нормальных библиотек позволяют автоматически определять нужные флаги - обычно через [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config), но у wxWidgets свой костыльный `wx-config`.

Запускать его (а также ставить сам wxWidgets и компилятор) удобно из MSYS2.

- Сносите свой MinGW и wxWidgets, или хотя бы убираете MinGW из PATH, чтобы не мешался.
- Ставите MSYS2 [отсюда](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/).
- Запускаете ярлыком `MSYS2 UCRT64`. Если сделано правильно, в терминале будет написано `UCRT64` фиолетовыми буквами.
- Обновляетесь командой `pacman -Syuu`. Если консоль закроется - открыть и повторить команду еще раз для завершения обновления.
- Ставите себе GCC, GDB, и wxWidgets:

  ```sh
  pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-wxwidgets3.2-msw
  ```
- Пробуете скомпилировать тестовую программу. Я взял код [отсюда](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/overview_helloworld.html) и компилировал командой:

  ```sh
  g++ my_code.cpp -static `wx-config --cflags --libs --static`
  ```

  Обратите внимание на обратные кавычки, они запускают команду `wx-config` и подставляют ее вывод во флаги `g++`.
- Теперь можно настоить Eclipse, чтобы он делал то же самое. Меняете там путь до компилятора на `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`, во флаги компилятора пишете вывод `wx-config --cflags`, а во флаги линковщика `-static` и вывод `wx-config --libs --static`.